# Stop html formatting in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Thought I should do a new question rather than extend the other, sorry if that was the wrong thing to do.

I am having another issue with TinyMCE. When I want enter something like a  single dash, when I submit my changes the editor will just remove it and I would have to 2 dashes in order to show 1. Of course I would know what to do but I don't want to make my website live expecting the people using it to know that they have to do that. Is there a way to disable the html formatting TinyMCE does?

This is my current setup:

```
      tinymce.init({

          selector: "textarea",
          allow_html_in_named_anchor: true,
          valid_elements: "*[*]",
          verify_html: false,
          plugins: [

              "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",

              "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",

              "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",


          ],
          toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",


      });
```

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: TinyMCE is an HTML editor - creating HTML is what it is designed to do.  When you say you want to "disable" the HTML formatting what exactly would you want instead?  If you don't want HTML the most obvious question is why you have chosen to se an HTML WYSISYG editing tool.  Can you clarify?

Comment: It does what I'm needing it to. I was looking for a way to see if it was possible for something like: if a user was wanting to write pizza\burger they could do that instead of having to do pizza\\burger if that makes sense?

Comment: See my reply below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE will not do anything (on its own) to a single backslash that you type into the editor.

Open this TinyMCE Fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/HLgaab/7

...and type in a single backslash.  You will see in the adjacent `<div>` that the single backslash is maintained.

You will also note that if you are using JavaScript to process the HTML as a string that the backslash has a special meaning and must be escaped.

For example, if you are trying to load content into the editor using JavaScript you would have to properly escape the backslash so that JavaScript does not interpret it incorrectly:

```
editor.setContent('<p>pizza\\burger</p>');
```

...is correct but...

```
editor.setContent('<p>pizza\burger</p>');
```

...is incorrect and the `\b` is treated as an escape sequence as opposed to simple characters.

If you are pre or post processing the content using JavaScript you need to properly escape the content.

Comment: ah okay thank you, I've been looking about it all wrong, thank you for your help!